# what exactly does a positive lookahead match?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my expression:

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z0-9\'\s]{2,50}$/m
```

Can someone provide an example of what this could match? I thought that the `?=.*[a-zA-Z]` meant the beginning of a string.

Comment: The `^` means the beginning of the string.

Comment: @chris85 right but what does the positive lookahead mean?

Comment: Don't include that part. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

A lookahead (as a lookbehind) is only a test at a position in the string. It doesn't consume characters, this is the reason why it is a called a zero-width assertion.

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` means "followed by zero or more characters except newlines *(the dot by default doesn't match newlines)* and an ascii letter".

Since the lookahead is after a *start of the string anchor* `^`, this means that the test is performed from this position in the string *(so the start of the string)* until the end of the line *(if there is a letter in the line the test succeeds)*.

So if there is no ascii letter in the line the whole pattern will fail because this test fails.

The goal of this lookahead in this particular pattern is to ensure there is at least one letter, because `^[A-Za-z0-9\'\s]{2,50}$` *(so the same but without this test)* may allow strings like `"'''''''''''''"` or `"       "` or `" 123 ''123 1237 "` without any letters.

As an aside the pattern can be written in this way for better performances:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9\'\s]{2,50}$)[0-9\'\s]*+[A-Za-z0-9\'\s]+
```

or

```
^(?=[0-9\'\s]*+[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z\'\s]{2,50}$
```

Note: note sure that the backslash before the single quote is needed *(except if the pattern is in a single quoted string)*.

Comment: Why does the 2,50 belong in the lookahead versus the end of the regex pattern, as im used to writing.